# Remove duplicate array elements using pointer arithmetic

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

This is algorithm for removing duplicate elements from array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i, n = 5, j, k, arr[5] = {1, 2, 1, 2, 4};
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
        for (k = j; k < n - 1; k++) {
          arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
        }
        n--;
        j--;
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

How could this be written with pointer arithmetic?

I need something like this:

```
int *p=arr;
while(p<arr+n){
    p++;
}
```

Comment: A note on code style: single letter index variables are often considered acceptable, but you have so many single-character things here (between operators and variables) that reading this is like staring at alphabet soup.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very expensive way to do things. A much cheaper way would be to use a linked list or binary tree structure instead of arrays, but if you insist on using arrays, your question is answered on this link:

https://engineeringstudentshub.wordpress.com/c-programs-for-u/array_programs/4-remove-duplicate-elements-in-an-array-using-c-program/

I hope that helps